# Why nano and rnano are different?

Tags: linux, editor, nano

I tried to edit files by using nano and rnano. The latter is really in restrict mode, but they are exactly same binary files. Why do they behave differently?

```
# which nano rnano
/usr/bin/nano
/bin/rnano

# md5sum /usr/bin/nano /bin/rnano
fa670e309a033718bad4b2051f5974fd  /usr/bin/nano
fa670e309a033718bad4b2051f5974fd  /bin/rnano
```

(In ubuntu 12.04 x64 LTS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They behave differently because of the argument vector (`argv`), whose first element (`argv[0]`) contains the name of the file being executed.

Because `rnano` is a separate file from `nano` (even though it is just a symbolic link), it has its own, separate `argv[0]`.

You can see this check in [nano.c](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/trunk/nano/src/nano.c?root=nano&content-type=text%2Fplain)'s main function:

```
/* If the executable filename starts with 'r', enable restricted
 * mode.
 */
if (*(tail(argv[0])) == 'r')
    SET(RESTRICTED);
```

You can also test this with a simple shell script. Create a shell script with only one statement, `echo $0`. Then, create a symbolic link to it with a separate name. Observe the difference.